# Debugging Requests Error

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an app that utilizes requests to access an API's (Discogs) database. I want to be able to see what URL Requests is actually requesting during a `.get` command to solve the following problem:

When I manually use an HTTP request to get data from discogs by entering the following URL:

```
http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=master&year=2007&format=album&artist=Radiohead
```

I receive results in JSON format. However, when I use requests in the following manner:

```
uri = http://api.discogs.com/database/search
parameters = {'format': 'album', 'year': '2008', 'type': 'master', 'page': 1, 'artist': 'Radiohead'}
headers = (personal information redacted)
requests.get(uri, params=parameters, headers=self._headers)
```

I get no results (this is through a discogs client wrapper that parses the results and returns them as objects -- the parsing, which I haven't included in this code, seems to work fine and I've isolated the problem to requests).

Could anyone either tell me what's wrong with my `.get` request or tell me how I can use requests to produce the URL it is actually requesting (with the parameters) so I can debug on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inspect the request before it is sent you can `prepare` it.

```
req = requests.Request(url=uri, params=params, headers=headers)
prep = req.prepare()
print(prep.url)
```

Prints

```
http://api.discogs.com/database/search?year=2008&type=master&page=1&format=album&artist=Radiohead´
```

Answer (score 1):

The `requests` library uses the `urllib3` library, which in turn uses the standard python `logging` library to log debug messages. The following configuration will show you what exact requests are being run:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This configures the `logging` module to show debug-level messages (and up) on stderr.

Running your example URL and parameters, I see:

```
>>> import logging
>>> import requests
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> uri = 'http://api.discogs.com/database/search'
>>> parameters = {'format': 'album', 'year': '2008', 'type': 'master', 'page': 1, 'artist': 'Radiohead'}
>>> r = requests.get(uri, params=parameters)
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): api.discogs.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /database/search?artist=Radiohead&year=2008&type=master&page=1&format=album HTTP/1.1" 200 379
>>> r.json()
{u'pagination': {u'per_page': 50, u'items': 1, u'pages': 1, u'urls': {}, u'page': 1}, u'results': [{u'style': [u'Experimental', u'Indie Rock'], u'thumb': u'http://api.discogs.com/image/R-90-1379425-1214572945.jpeg', u'format': [u'File', u'MPEG-4', u'Album', u'Copy Protected'], u'country': u'UK', u'title': u'Radiohead - In Rainbows - From The Basement', u'uri': u'/Radiohead-In-Rainbows-From-The-Basement/master/97298', u'label': [u'_Xurbia_Xendless Limited'], u'catno': u'none', u'year': u'2008', u'genre': [u'Electronic', u'Rock'], u'resource_url': u'http://api.discogs.com/masters/97298', u'type': u'master', u'id': 97298}]}
```

So for me, without additional headers set, the URL certainly works as expected.